# After Change Package name it giving Error

Tags: android, package

How I Replace this from all android project instead doing manually?? It happen after change the package name

> package com.companyname.xyz.xyz.asyncTasks

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;



import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mell on 3/27/2017.
 */

public class CreatedOrderListAPI extends AsyncTask<Void ,Void,Boolean> {

    private static final String TAG = CreatedOrderListAPI.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private String jsonString, response = "";

    private PlacedOrderListModel placedOrderListModel;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewOrders;
    private List<PlacedOrderListModel> PlacedordersListModels;
    private CreatedOrderAdapter createdOrdersAdapter;

    private Context context;
    private View rootview;
```

I have to change in all file of studio....

Comment: show error log .

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.companyname.xyz'

Comment: what you exactly want

Comment: i just want to rename this "package com.companyname.xyz.xyz.asyncTasks"   to "package com.companyname.xyz.asyncTasks"......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first read

> Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java
>   package name, such as com.example.myapp. This ID uniquely identifies
>   your app on the device and in Google Play Store. If you want to upload
>   a new version of your app, the application ID (and the certificate you
>   sign it with) must be the same as the original APK—if you change the
>   application ID, Google Play Store treats the APK as a completely
>   different app. So once you publish your app, you should never change
>   the application ID.

If your app is not live in play store then Just change from  here

Open **`build.gradle`**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.companyname.xyz.xyz.asyncTasks"
     .....
      }
```

**FYI**

**Don't change Package name Manually .**

Comment: Can I do this.....First we delete an old application which is on play store and after that we upload the new one

Comment: @RISHABHSAXENA `we upload the new one` which is live ??

Comment: Yes....Actually that old application is demo...now application is almost complete